# Suggestion for sql scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, business-logic, unique-index

I am having two columns in table

```
InventoryId | RevisionId
-------------------------
1   |   1
2   |   1
2   |   2
2   |   2
3   |   1
3   |   2
3   |   3
3   |   3
```

but from now on I want to prevent following records

```
2   |   2
2   |   2
3   |   3
3   |   3
```

So I thought to create a unique index on these two columns
but the table having so much existing data. So anything we can do this situation.
Any suggestion?

Comment: so the existing data `2 | 2` is allowed but any new rows may not have both the same value ?

Comment: Do you have a unique id on each row?

Comment: you should remove duplicate values and add unique key

Comment: Either you first remove existing duplate values and then add your unique key, or you prevent now duplicates with a trigger

Comment: @Mano the table having so much of existing data which can be used as history so I can not do that

Comment: @GuidoG how to prevent now with trigger

Comment: what is the primary key of this table ?

Comment: Add an other table with all the combinations you don't want to insert again. Check for this table for every insert into the original table, if combination exists then stop inserting.

Comment: @Squirrel the primary key of this table is 'Id'

Comment: It could be done with a check constraint, check the edit in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trigger to prevent new rows being added with duplicate values

look at this example

```
create trigger TR_UI_YourTable on YourTable
for update, insert as
begin
     set nocount on

     if exists (select 1 from inserted i where i.InventoryId = i.RevisionId)
     begin
          ;throw 99001, 'no dupes allowed anymore...', 1
     end
end
```

A better solution would be to move the duplicates to a seperate table for history, and then add a check constraint on these 2 columns

**EDIT**

you could do it by an check constraint like this

```
alter table yourtable
add constraint chk_dupes 
  check ((InventoryId <> RevisionId) or (id <= 12345))
```

where 12345 is the highest value of the column `id` now.
You will have to test it a bit if it works on all situations.
Also, it will only work if all new rows have a value in `id` that is larger then the current highest value (12345 in my example)